# Webkit border-radius bleed issue when using -webkit-transform

Tags: css, webkit

I made a simple script in jQuery that takes an image and slowly rotates it. 
[Link to example](http://nixkelly.com/css/rotate_image)

```
     deg = 0;
     derp = false;
     function callRotate(){
      if(!derp){
        setInterval(rotate, 50);
      }
     }
    function rotate(){
      $("#rotate_me > img").css({"-webkit-transform":"rotate("+ deg +"deg)", "-moz-transform":"rotate("+ deg +"deg)"});
    deg+=.2;
    }
    callRotate();
```

I decided to put a border-radius on the div equal to 1/2 of the div height to make the image look like a circle. The rotation looks fine in Firefox 4.0.1, but when i tested it in Chrome the image bleeds over the border-radius as soon as the rotation starts. Does anyone know of a way to prevent the image from bleeding over?

Comment: Instead of passing a string to `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, you should pass a function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval

Comment: you don't need to create an additional closure. You can use `setInterval(rotate, 50)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the image the background of the div in CSS, then rotate the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can give `border-radius` to `img`, but it wont work in Opera (it's not working anyway).

Answer (score 0):

try transform-style:preserve-3d

http://blog.csdn.net/w20101310/article/details/52298636

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.